# How to modify a particular frequency in a sound file in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js, modulation

So basically i am making audio equaliser in p5.js and i dont know how to modulate a particular freq. in a soundFile
if anyone know please provide some insight to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a Band Stop filter. This is the inverse of a Band Pass filter. A Band Pass filter leaves frequencies around a given center unchanged while reducing the amplitude of frequencies above and below. A Band Stop filter does the reverse, it reduces the amplitude of frequencies around a given center while leaving those above and below unchanged. In p5.sound this is accomplished using the filter type `'notch'`. There is no special class for this filter type (like `p5.BandPass`), so you just use the generic `p5.Filter` and pass the type to the constructor. Here is an example based on the p5.sound reference:

```js
let fft, noise, filter;

function setup() {
  let cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  cnv.mousePressed(makeNoise);
  fill(255, 0, 255);

  filter = new p5.Filter('notch');
  // (lower res = wider band rejection)
  // Note: When using a 'notch' filter, in order to filter out the
  // same range a frequencies that you would be filtering for
  // using a 'bandpass' filter, you need to use a much smaller res
  // value. I'm not sure why this is.
  filter.res(0.2);

  // This example uses p5.Noise for demonstation purposes, but it
  // should work just as well with a p5.SoundFile created with
  // loadSound
  noise = new p5.Noise();
  // Don't play the noise directly
  noise.disconnect();
  // Instead pass it to the filter (which will be connected to
  // audio output by default).
  noise.connect(filter);

  // This is just for the display
  fft = new p5.FFT();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  // set the BandPass frequency based on mouseX
  let freq = map(mouseX, 0, width, 20, 22050, true);
  filter.freq(freq);

  // draw filtered spectrum
  let spectrum = fft.analyze();
  noStroke();
  for (let i = 0; i < spectrum.length; i++) {
    let x = map(i, 0, spectrum.length, 0, width);
    let h = -height + map(spectrum[i], 0, 255, height, 0);
    rect(x, height, width / spectrum.length, h);
  }
  if (!noise.started) {
    text('tap here and drag to change frequency', 10, 20, width - 20);
  } else {
    text('Frequency: ' + round(freq) + 'Hz', 20, 20, width - 20);
  }
}

function makeNoise() {
  // see also: `userStartAudio()`
  noise.start();
  noise.amp(0.2, 0.2);
}

function mouseReleased() {
  noise.amp(0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It Works but could you explain how can i alter mid freq. of a soundFile

Comment: You need to define “alter” and you need to define “mid frequency”. Are you trying to shift the pitch of an entire song? Like to transpose it up a number of half steps?

Comment: Yes,that what i am trying to do.